# Show the topics belong to the tags of one topic in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I don't know what this feature should be called.... so I can just describe the basic scenario:
topic has_many tags through :tagging
tag has_many topics through :tagging

so, in the @topic show page, I want to display all topics which have the tags that belong to @topic( Not with the same tags, just one common tag)

One possible approach is

```
tags.each do |tag|
  tag.topics.each do |topic|
    topic
  end
end
```

but this would result dulipications in topic, since a topic may belongs to different tags

I find that it's possible to use `ids.uniq` to remove the dulicates in an array. So would this be a solution? And how can I get the `topic_ids`? Maybe `topic_ids= topic_ids + topic.id`?

Comment: you already have `topic_ids`, use `@tag.topic_ids` to get ids of topics belong to a tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you all topics that have tag_id's matching those associated with `@topic`.  Note that this will also include the original `@topic`:

```
topics = Topic.joins(:taggings).
               where(:taggings => {:tag_id => @topic.taggings.pluck(:tag_id) }).
               uniq
```

If you want to exclude the original, just add an additional `where` to the chain:

```
where("taggings.topic_id != ?", @topic.id)
```

There is a slightly more efficient way to do this using a subquery instead of the initial database call to get the associated `tag_id`s, but this will probably suffice.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer acts_as_taggable_on then I use

```
<%= raw @topic.find_related_tags.map { |t| link_to(t.title, topic_path(t)}.join(" ") %>
```

Comment: How does this retrieve a list of related topics from the original topic?